# Spring Boot and JWT - post request returns page not found

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I'm trying to implement JWT in my Spring Boot application (following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot-api) tutorial), and I have a UserController page that is like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {



    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;



    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;



    public UserController(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository,
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }



    @PostMapping("/users/sign-up")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        applicationUserRepository.save(user); //Salvataggio sul DB
    } 

}
```

Using Postman, if I do a POST request to page `http://localhost:8080/users/sign-up` it returns me 404 page not found error.
I have no idea where to look for the error or missing part. The only different thing I've done from the tutorial was to add `(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })` for my `@SpringBootApplication` to disable default login page.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies here:

```
@PostMapping("/users/sign-up")
```

This is because your rest controller is already mapped to the to `/users`

Replace it with:

```
@PostMapping("sign-up")
```

Do it like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;



    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;



    public UserController(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository,
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }



    @PostMapping("sign-up")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        applicationUserRepository.save(user); //Salvataggio sul DB
    } 

}
```

Are you making postman request correctly? 
Try:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "password"
}' http://localhost:8080/users/sign-up
```

and you get a `404`, then check other files of your project.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I have the same problem. I've also tried replacing it with "/sign-up" instead of just "sign-up" but didn't work

Comment: even when you cleaned the cache and restarted the server?

Comment: yes. I've tried adding @PostMapping("/users/sign-up") and deleting @RequestMapping("/users")  before class name, but didn't change

Comment: try `@PostMapping("sign-up/")`  or `http://localhost:8080/users/sign-up/` for postman

Comment: Nothing changed